# Efficient and smooth scrolling of top view just like in facebook app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a top view and a tableview below it. My requirement is while table view is scrolling up, the top view should also scroll up along with the first row. When the table view scrolls down the top view should also scroll along with the current row (not after all rows scrolls down).

Hope I'm clear on above. If anyone has some working code, will appreciate your help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this delegate for this

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint point =quotesTableView.contentOffset;
    //Do your coading in this
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm using delegate but unfortunately that doesn't help much.

Comment: have you implementing UIScrollViewDelegate?

Comment: Yup. I just looking for a piece of code that does similar to my requirements. My animations are not smooth, when user swipes fast his finger. I just want very smooth animations like FB or Google+ apps.